# How to add a java.sql.Date object to the JSON array?

Tags: java, vert.x

Trying to add a Date object to a JSON array as following:

```
io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray data = new io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray();
try {
  long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();  
  java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(millis);  
  data.add(date);
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
  LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

I got an exception of 'Illegal type in JsonObject: class java.sql.Date'. Is there any good idea to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use an `Instant` from your millis value :

```
data.add(Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis));
```

If you really need to manipulate a `java.sql.Date` (I wonder why), you must convert it before adding the value in your `JsonArray`. For example :

```
data.add(new java.util.Date(date.getTime()).toInstant());
```

In both case, here's the `toString` of your `JsonArray` :

```
["2018-04-02T21:57:16.307Z"]
```

If you need to recreate an instance of `java.sql.date` from your `JsonArray` :

```
 Instant instant = data.getInstant(0);
 java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(instant.toEpochMilli());
```

P.S : this is a Java >= 8 answer

Comment: Thank you, Idriss, for your answer!
To keep the original schema unchanged, I do really need java.sql.Date object to feed io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLClient.updateWithParams(String, JsonArray, Handler<AsyncResult<UpdateResult>>).

Comment: @Ming You can create a new instance of `java.sql.Date` after reading your `JsonArray` entry in your Handler ;) ...

Comment: Handler is used to process the result of updateWithParams(), not the input params.

Comment: @Ming I've updated my answer to show you how to recreate a instance of `java.sql.date` from your `JsonArray`.